# specify the size of UISlider's thumb image

Tags: ios, uikit, uislider

I am trying to change the size of thumb image of UISlider. So far the only answer I found was to provide an image of different size or to create it programatically. What is the correct way of specifying the size of UISlider's thumb image?

Comment: Use same width*height image. It can help you.